# Which bystander did Post Malone play as?

Tags: casting, cameo, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In the credits to *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, it is listed that Post Malone voice acted one of the Brooklyn bystanders. My question though is, which one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No official words I can get about it but [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4633694/characters/nm8203589) claims Malone said this line:

> Brooklyn Bystander : [looking at a glitched stoplight]  I think it's a [Banksy](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/the-story-behind-banksy-4310304/).

Going through [official script](http://origin-flash.sonypictures.com/ist/awards_screenplays/SV_screenplay.pdf), only one Brooklynite have a speaking line and it's same as IMDb and you yourself said he was credited as Brooklyn bystanders.

[ET Online](https://www.etonline.com/spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-producers-cast-talk-celeb-cameos-and-that-poignant-stan-lee) confirms it:

> “Post Malone gets a pretty big laugh in the movie,” Lord said of the GRAMMY-nominated rapper, who contributed the song "Sunflower" to the Spider-Verse soundtrack and has a cameo as a "Banksy enthusiast" Brooklyn bystander.